# How to wait for Bootstrap's data-binding in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to emulate a click on a button that opens a Bootstrap modal. Unfortunately, Bootstrap takes some time to bind everything and document.ready and document.load doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you create a fiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The app's structure, that is causing this problem is too complicated for a fiddle.